# How can I merge two or more dictionaries in a list?

Tags: python-2.7

Is there any nice pythonic way of merging dictionaries within a list?

What I have:

```py
[
    { 'name': "Jack" },
    { 'age': "28" }
]
```

What I would like:

```py
[
    { 'name': "Jack", 'age': "28" }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method that uses [`dict.update()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update). In my opinion it's a very readable solution:

```
data = [{'name': 'Jack'}, {'age': '28'}]

new_dict = {}
for d in data:
    new_dict.update(d)

new_data = [new_dict]

print new_data
```

**OUTPUT**

> [{'age': '28', 'name': 'Jack'}]

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension:

```
final_list = [{key: one_dict[key]
               for one_dict in initial_list
               for key in one_dict.keys()}]
```

Edit: the list comprehension was backwards

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3, you can use [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> ld = [
...       { 'name': "Jack" },
...       { 'age': "28" }
...      ]
>>> [dict(ChainMap(*ld))]

 [{'name': 'Jack', 'age': '28'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = reduce(lambda one, two: dict(one.items() + two.items()), 
       [{'name': 'Jack'}, {'age': '28'}, {'last_name': 'Daniels'}])
print(out)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'age': '28', 'last_name': 'Daniels', 'name': 'Jack'}
```